# Alternative version of triangle inequality

Tags: inequality

I'm trying to figure out if we can claim that for $x, y$ real:
$$
|x-y|\leq|x| +  |y|
$$

From the triangle inequality we know that:

$$|x+y|\leq |x| + |y|$$

Is there anyway to determine a relationship between $|x+y|$ and $|x-y|$ that can help with this proof?

Can I claim that since $|y|=|-y|$ the first equation should hold?

Comment: Yes, you use just that.

Comment: try to square it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
                       |x−y| = |x+(-y)| ≤ |x|+|-y| = |x|+|y|

                                |x−y| ≤ |x|+|y|
```